# Create a button that links to a website from within an Outlook 2007 signature

Tags: outlook-2007, button, signature

Apparently, Outlook 2007 no longer supports embedded HTML code within signatures.  I had no difficulty adding a DONATION button to my signature, but I'm unable to link from that button to a website.  Does anybody have a suggestion to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Just put a link in instead of a button.